# How can I get the next closest integer out of 2 integers?

Tags: java, integer

Let's say I have an `int pick = 3` and I also have an `int minus = 0` and `int plus = 7`.

How can I get the number closest to my `int pick` number?
So in this case the distance from `int pick` to `int minus` would be 3 and the distance from `int pick` to `int plus` would be 4, so I want `int minus` to be chosen.

All of the ints are changable values, I just chose some numbers to show as an example, is there a loop or if-statement that could solve this?

Comment: There's a function called `Math.abs()` which gets the absolute value of a number: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-math-abs-method-examples/. If you were to subtract minus and plus from pick, then compare the absolutes, the smaller number would be the closest integer (you should also cater for numbers of equal distance)

Comment: @mint But as the OP seems to just want a number return value, in the case of a tie presumably we can just return either minus or plus.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - You're right, in this instance your answer suits the question perfectly and an equal distance does not matter :) . But it's also good to note that there is a possibility for a 'draw' when looking for the closest number, even if it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ternary or if expression here:

```java
public static int nearest(int minus, int plus, int pick) {
    return Math.abs(minus - pick) < Math.abs(plus - pick) ? minus : plus;
}

System.out.println(nearest(0, 7, 3));  // 0
System.out.println(nearest(0, 4, 3));  // 4
```